# PHP iconv function to handle foreign language characters

Tags: php, csv, utf

My application is writing path into CSV file while building the CSV export using below  code.

```
 $path = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $thisRow['path'] ) ;
```

If path having polish characters then i.e. 'C:\Users\Desktop\Przejście graniczne' then **$path value is displaying as blank**.

If I comment above code and just assign the like below then paths showing correctly.

```
 $path =  $thisRow['path']  ;
```

But seems like this is not elegant solution hence want to know how  to solve this issue in more correct way?

***Solution***

Used function utf8_encode() during encoding and now its working as desired.

```
 $path = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', utf8_encode($thisRow['path']) ) ;
```

Comment: Since `ś` does not exist in ISO-8859-1, this conversion cannot be done. But iconv provides a transliteration option (which will turn ś into s). You can use this by suffixing the target charset with `//TRANSLIT`: `iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $thisRow['path'] ) ;`

Answer (score 1):

Read CSV file in Big5

```
<?php
$path = 'test.csv';
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); // 設置內部字符編碼為 UTF-8

if(($open = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE){
    while (($rows = fgetcsv($open,  ",")) !== FALSE){  
        foreach($rows as &$row){
            $newStr = iconv("big5", 'UTF-8', $row); // 轉換編碼
            print_r($newStr);
        }
    }
    fclose($open);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
$chars = ['\u0179','\u0119','\u0105','\u0107', '\u0142','\u0144','\u00f3', '\u015b','\u017a', '\u017c', '\u0104', '\u0106', '\u0118', '\u0141', '\u0143', '\u00d3', '\u015a', '\u017b'];


$polish = ['&#377;','&#281;','&#261;','&#263;', '&#322;','&#322;', '&#243;',  '&#347;', '&#378;',  '&#380;',   '&#260;',  '&#262;',  '&#280;',    '&#321;', '&#323;',       '&#211;',     '&#346;',   '&#379;' ];


$path=json_decode(str_replace($chars,$polish,json_encode($thisRow['path'])));
```

to find chars and convert to polish char

Comment: Thanks for help but I want generic solution ...not Polish language specific one...Path should be available in all cases, currently its showing as blank for Polish characters